# Library should trigger event on external api call or not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, eventemitter

I'm using a library which draw some rectangle inside a canvas. When I click on one of them, a selection event changed event is emitted. But when I changed the selection programatically, none are emitted.

In my opinion, even if I change selection programatically, event must be emitted, because it happens. Am I right ?

```js
myLibrary.events(SelectionChangedEvent).subscribe(ev => {
    // Trigger on sélection modified by click (when event come from internal library)
});

// Doesn't trigger my SelectionChangedEvent
myLibrary.changeSelection(newSelection);
```

Generally, must we trigger event everytime it happens, even if the application knows it happens ?

I think we have to; specially if my function myLibrary.changeSelection() checks some parameters or do some process which could failed.

Comment: So your question is more about a library conception issue rather than a programming one? If so you might be better off going on a sister site such as https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, see their FAQ and our [help/on-topic]. FWIW, I do think that the event should be triggered ― Why would you care where the "selection" action is coming from? It happened.

Comment: @PaulStenne when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)